# MySQL 8.0 Generated Columns Problems

Tags: mysql, ms-access, generated-columns

I'm upgrading an Access 2016 back-end database to MySQL 8.0 and having problems with the generated columns.  I used a third-party tool to migrate my Access tables to MySQL, and for the most part it worked fine.  The Access calculated columns are not migrated. Or rather, they are, but as standard columns.  I need to go in and redefine the calculations in MySQL.

In Access, I have a Heading column which combines title, last name, first name, spouse name, spouse last name into a single heading.  Here is the Access calculation which works just fine.

```
IIf([UseTitle],[Title] & " ","") & IIf(IsNull([DonorFirstName]),[DonorLastName],[DonorFirstName] & IIf(IsNull([SpouseName])," " & [DonorLastName],IIf(IsNull([SpouseLastName])," and " & [SpouseName] & " " & [DonorLastName]," " & [DonorLastName] & " and " & [SpouseName] & " " & [SpouseLastName])))
```

If this person wants to use a title (such as "Mr. & Mrs."), insert the title. If no first name, the last name's a company, so add the LastName field, otherwise add the FirstName field. If no spouse, add space and LastName field. If spouse with same last name, add " and " plus SpouseLastName. Otherwise, add LastName plus " and " plus SpouseFirstName plus space plus SpouseLastName.  So now you either have "Mr. & Mrs. John and Jane Doe" or "Mr. & Mrs. John Doe and Jane Smith".

I tried doing this in MySQL using a combination of CONCATs and IFs like this:

```
`Heading` varchar(509) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci GENERATED ALWAYS AS (concat(if(((`UseTitle` = 0) or (`Title` is null)),_utf8mb3'',concat(`Title`,_utf8mb3' ')),if((ifnull(`DonorFirstName`,_utf8mb3'') = _utf8mb3''),`DonorLastName`,concat(`DonorFirstName`,_utf8mb3' ',if((ifnull(`SpouseName`,_utf8mb3'') = _utf8mb3''),`DonorLastName`,if((ifnull(`SpouseLastName`,_utf8mb3'') = _utf8mb3''),concat(_utf8mb3'and ',`SpouseName`,_utf8mb3' ',`DonorLastName`),concat(`DonorLastName`,_utf8mb3' and ',`SpouseName`,_utf8mb3' ',`SpouseLastName`))))))) STORED,
```

This does NOT work, and in fact causes an error in the table DDL.  It seems to update properly, but when I try to open the table design in MySQL Workbench, it gives me an error saying `Error parsing DDL for tableName`

When I choose to view the DDL in another tab, the generated field line is identified with an asterisk, and shows this:

```
`Heading` varchar(509) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci GENERATED ALWAYS AS (concat(if(((`UseTitle` = 0) or (`Title` is null)),_utf8mb3'',concat(`Title`,_utf8mb3' ')), `DonorFirstName`,_utf8mb3' ',`DonorLastName`)) VIRTUAL,
```

The '' after the _utf8mb3 is underlined, and hovering over it shows:

```
"Syntax error: extraneous input found - expected 'comma'"
```

Luckily, this is a brand new database, and I can simply drop and recreate the table, but not if I cannot figure out how to properly generate that column.

I'm obviously doing something wrong here.  Is there a correct way to make this generated column properly work?

Comment: please provide your complete table,especially the columns needed

Comment: please show output of `show create table yourtablename`

Comment: i tested your Heading and mysql 8.0.,21 doesn't show any problems at all, it shows forevery _utf8mb3 a warning.

Comment: show create table gives the same as above for that column. The _utf8mb3 gets put in there automatically. Mine shows big X in left margin of the DDL, so it's definitely an error, not a warning.

Comment: Please advise why I was down-voted.  I went to a lot of trouble to state the issue concisely and give examples of problem.  What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your alter table command is incorrect. A valid command would look like this. Remove all `_utf8mb3` and correct the `if` and `concat` native functions.

```
ALTER TABLE tableName
`Heading` varchar(509) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci GENERATED ALWAYS AS (
    concat(
        if( ((not `UseTitle`) or IsNull(`Title`)),
            '',
            concat(`Title`,' ', `DonorFirstName`, ' ',`DonorLastName`)
        )
    )
) VIRTUAL,
```

PS: `concat(value1, value2)` will return null if `any` value within the function is null.

`concat_ws('', value1, value2)` will ignore nulls and add all non null values.

Comment: Thanks Krish. Mine was just like yours except I put (`UseTitle`=0) instead of (not `UseTitle`). Some parens were different, so I fixed all that. But the ```_utf8mb3``` are all added automatically after I execute the DDL. I'm using create table instead of alter table. Then the new table is corrupt or something, because I can't open it in design mode.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to those who answered or commented.
If I make the changes in the SQL editor, it works just fine.  The changes are accepted as expected.  Still, I get a hard error trying to view the table definition in MySQL Workbench. So, the problem seems to be there instead.  I will re-post the question differently to solve that issue.